# Passing variable into HTML attribute inside ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a directive that will load a page located in a file called 'page-<name of page>.html'. The aim is that this directive should accept the page's name as an attribute. The reason for this is because the directive will be used inside an ng-repeat, and therefore the value of that attribute will vary
as the directive is called multiple times. The aim is that the page-panel load the page as per its argument, however upon trying this myself, Angular tries to open the literal file 'page-{{page.name}}.html' instead of substituting in the name of the page in that iteration of the ng-repeat. I have also tried it without the quotes, without the braces, and without both, but they all fail.
Does anybody know of any way I can accomplish this?

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="PageController as ctrl">
  [...]
  <div ng-repeat="page in ctrl.pages" ng-show="page.name == ctrl.currentPage">
    {{page.name}}
    <page-panel pageName="{{page.name}}"></page-panel>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('agora-vote', []);
app.controller('PageController', function(){
  this.pages = [{name:"Page1"},{name:"Page2"}];
  this.currentPage = "Page1";
  this.getName = function(){
    return
  }
});
app.directive('pagePanel', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: function(elem, attr) {
      console.log(attr)
      return 'page-' + attr.pageName + '.html';
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Use the [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive.

Answer (score 0):

I have made one change and looks it is working fine.

```
 return 'page-' + attr.$attr.pagename + '.html';
```

The complete code is as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body ng-app="agora-vote" ng-controller="PageController as ctrl">
    [...]
    <div ng-repeat="page in ctrl.pages" ng-show="page.name == ballot.currentPage">
        {{page.name}}
        <page-panel pageName="{{page.name}}"></page-panel>
    </div>


    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('agora-vote', []);
        app.controller('PageController', function () {
            this.pages = [{ name: "Page1" }, { name: "Page2" }];
            this.currentPage = "Page1";
            this.getName = function () {
                return
            }
        });
        app.directive('pagePanel', function () {
            return {
                templateUrl: function (elem, attr) {
                    console.log(attr)
                    return 'page-' + attr.$attr.pagename + '.html';
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is $attr ?